# Returning a specific value if a joined row doesn't exist in a SELECT statement using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL tables containing:

1. some objects
2. some data about the objects with the type of data

For example:

```
    |---ID---|---NAME---|
    |   1    |  name1   |
    |   2    |  name2   |
    |   3    |  name3   |

    |---ID_OBJ---|---TYPE---|---VALUE---|
    |      1     |  type_1  |    val1   | 
    |      1     |  type_2  |    val2   | 
    |      2     |  type_1  |    val3   | 
    |      3     |  type_2  |    val4   |
```

I want to obtain all the information about each objects on one line. The problem is that I want the values of the nonexistent rows too :

```
    |---NAME---|---TYPE1---|---TYPE2---|
    |  name1   |    val1   |    val1   |
    |  name2   |    val3   |     NA    |
    |  name3   |     NA    |    val4   |
```

I don't really understand how to proceed to get this unexistant relationships. Is the `EXISTS` keyword a solution?

Edit: I can't activate the tablefunc extension because I don't manage the server myself so the solution explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/3468262) can't be easily used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)

Comment: The problem is that the database was designed using the EAV pattern, which is almost always a mistake. Now you can see just a small part of the reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Postgres supports `crosstab`, I think this is easily done using conditional aggregation if you know what columns you want:

```
select t1.name,
       coalesce(max(case when type = 'type_1' then value end), 'NA') as type_1,
       coalesce(max(case when type = 'type_2' then value end), 'NA') as type_2
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id_obj
group by t1.name;
```